# Comparing two dates in different format with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

I have 2 dates defined as a strings. If I would know the original date format, I would compare it like this:

```
import time
date1 = "1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM" # formatted like "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"
date2 = "1/1/2016"             # formatted like "%m/%d/%Y"
format1 = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"
format2 = "%m/%d/%Y"
if time.strptime(date1, format1) > time.strptime(date2, format2):
   pass
```

How can I compare it if I do not know the date format?

Comment: The best you'll be able to do is trying various formats and seeing if one succeeds. You might be able to speed that process up by examining the string beforehand to select which candidate formats to try first (and not bother with those that couldn't possibly work).

Comment: Thanks I did write my own solution of this problem with try - except block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parse it with `dateutil.parser.parse`. This method parse a string in one of the supported formats. And then compare it.

[`datautil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/) is a third-party module.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm searching for!

Answer (score 2):

> How can I compare it if I do not know the date format?

You can't. 
Every comparison assumes that you know what you are comparing.